# Using JSON_VALUE + JSON_QUERY to create new JSON

Tags: json, sql-server

I was wondering if it would be possible to reshape JSON and return it as JSON. I have JSON which, in simplified form, looks like:

- Name
- Details

  - fieldId
  - fieldValue
- Other

  - Id
  - Value

And would like to return:

- Name
- Details

  - fieldId
  - fieldValue

I can return Name and Details with `JSON_VALUE` and `JSON_QUERY` but would like it as one combined JSON field.

```
create table #test (
  [id] int,
  [json] varchar(max)
);

insert into #test (id, json) values (1, '{
  "Name": "Test 1",
  "Details": [
    {
      "fieldId": "100",
      "fieldValue": "ABC"
    }],
  "Other": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "Value": "ABC"
    }]
}');

insert into #test (id, json) values (2, '{
  "Name": "Test 2",
  "Details": [
    {
      "fieldId": "101",
      "fieldValue": "ABCD"
    }],
  "Other": [
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "Value": "ABCD"
    }]
}');

select id, JSON_VALUE(json, '$.Name'), JSON_QUERY(json, '$.Details')
from #test
```

Answer (score 3):

As an additional option, you may parse the JSON with `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema (columns definitions) and then build the new JSON again:

```
SELECT
   id,
   newjson = (
      SELECT Name, Details 
      FROM OPENJSON(json) WITH (
         Name varchar(max) '$.Name',
         Details nvarchar(max) '$.Details' AS JSON
      )
      FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
   )
FROM #test
```

And the same approach with `JSON_VALUE()` and `JSON_QUERY()`:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  newjson = (
     SELECT JSON_VALUE(json, '$.Name') AS [Name], JSON_QUERY(json, '$.Details') AS [Details]
     FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
  )   
FROM #test
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use [`JSON_MODIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to re-construct the JSON:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    JSON_MODIFY(
        JSON_MODIFY(
            '{}',
            '$.Name',
            JSON_VALUE(json, '$.Name')
        ),
        '$.Details',
        JSON_QUERY(json, '$.Details')
    ) AS new_json
FROM #test
```

An alternate would be to delete the `Other` node using `JSON_MODIFY` but you have to know the name of node(s) to remove.